# How to pivot a Pandas Dataframe - separate row for columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have csv file that I am reading into Pandas Data Frame in the following format:

```
Number|Name |v1|v2|v3|v4
100000|Name1|value1|value2|value3|value4
200000|Name2|value1|value2|value3|value4
300000|Name3|value1|value2|value3|value4
```

I would like to pivot it, so I have a separate row for each value with Number and Name:

```
Number| Name | values |
100000| Name1| value1 |
100000| Name1| value2 |
100000| Name1| value3 |
100000| Name1| value4 |
200000| Name2| value1 |
200000| Name2| value2 |
200000| Name2| value3 |
200000| Name2| value4 |
....
```

Comment: You can check melt

Comment: `df.set_index(["Number", "Name"]).stack()`?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

Comment: This is more *unpivot*, aka, `melt` or `unstack` as previously commented.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Number','Name'], value_vars=['v1','v2','v3','v4'])
```